# ASP.NET browser definition file not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I'm trying to detect some older hardware and mark it as isMobileDevice with the browser definition files.  This is in .NET 4.0 +

The user-agent is Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE)

So I added a browser file called WinCE.browser to my App_Browsers folder.  Stepping through the code I see it's detecting it as IE6to9 so I put the below in my file to detect when the user agent has Windows CE it should match on it and set the id to WinCE and isMobileBrowser = true but it's not working.  What am I missing here to get this to work.

```
   <!--
    You can find existing browser definitions at
    <windir>\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<ver>\CONFIG\Browsers
-->
<browsers>
    <browser id="WinCE" parentID="IE6to9">
        <identification>
          <userAgent match="Windows CE" />
        </identification>

        <capture>
        </capture>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="browser" value="Windows CE MSIE" />
            <capability name="isMobileDevice" value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

Answer (score 6):

Finally found the issue.  Apparently there is somewhat of a bug and it's been there since 2008

http://forums.asp.net/t/955969.aspx?Mastering+Browser+Definition+Files

Bugs
Some of you may have been trying this stuff and still saying, “It doesn’t work!”  Well, the problem is that there is a bug in ASP.NET related to compiling new browser files. Although Microsoft states that “.browser” files in the App_Browsers folder are detected and compiled on the fly, I have found out that this is not always the case.

From my own tests, below are some quirky behavior patterns I discovered that should help you during development.

·         The first .browser file created in the App_Browsers folder is detected and compiled with no problems.

·         Any additional .browsers files are not detected UNTIL a change is detected on the first file.

So, what this means is that if you create additional .browser files, you need to trigger a change on the first .browser file. You can do this by simply saving the first .browser file with your text editor without making any real modifications. This changes the modified date of the file which seems to be enough for ASP.NET to recompile all the .browser files. After creating several .browser files, I have noticed that if I see that changes to one of the files don’t take effect, then simply modifying the date of any of the other files seems to do the trick.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to have this marked as the accepted answer -- I've just lost nearly half a day to this problem, having only found this question late in to the search.